# Google Chrome seems to "Squish" Images?

Tags: html

So I'm designing and build a website for school as part of a project, on this page there are 3 images which in Internet Explorer and Firefox seem perfectly fine but when in Google Chrome, When ever you re-size the browser they seem squashed. I tried Googling it to see if there was a bug but nothing has popped up?

Picture comparing Google Chrome with Internet Explorer : http://prntscr.com/22cr26

Live site (So you can see for yourself) : http://baileywhite.comule.com/penguin/Shop.html

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 I would add code but It would be adding every line of code due to I have no idea what part of the code is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have width and height attributes on the img tag that are not the same ratio as the original image, and that is what is "squishing" the image.